# Using a long as a primary key in an MVC5 model

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, primary-key, long-integer

I am writing a C# MVC5 internet application and am using the following attribute as a primary key in a model:

```
[Key]
public long id { get; set; }
```

I have written a context class, created a controller with views, and when I browse to the Index action result, I am getting this error:

```
The 'id' property on 'MapCompany' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'.
```

At this line of code:

```
return View(await db.mapCompanies.ToListAsync());
```

How can I get this code working?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the top of the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The 'Id' property on 'MapCompany' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'. ]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +392
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +105
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +133
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +737
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +378
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +280
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +441
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +24
```

Comment: Update your MapCompany table primary key to bigint and not null constraint and then this error will be gone..

Comment: Can I get entity framework do do this for me, as I would rather not tamper with the database manually? I am using CodeFirst.

Comment: I am creating a blank database from the start, and the scaffolding code that is generated has the above error. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Post the top of the stack trace.

Comment: Does the above stack trace have enough information?

Comment: Not really clear yet. If you really didn't alter any of the generated code then it might be a bug in the scaffolding. Can you find the generated HTML for the Id (HiddenFor or something) ?

Comment: If I use an int, the controllers and views all work correctly. Are there any additional code values that I need to add for a long. It should be very simple.